# How to add multiple track to stream in alexa?

Tags: php, alexa-skills-kit, alexa-voice-service

I am working on alexa for the first time and I am developing a music app. I need to add multiple track of one artist and play it continuously. I am unable to do so. However, one song is working properly but unable to add and play multiple song.

Here is my code,

```
$response = '{
        "version" : "1.0",

        "response" : {
            "outputSpeech": {
              "type": "PlainText",
              "text": "Playing song for Acon"
            },
            '.$card.',
            "directives": [
              {
                "type": "AudioPlayer.Play",
                "playBehavior": "REPLACE_ALL",
                "audioItem": {
                  "stream": {
                "token": "track1",
                "url": "https://p.scdn.co/mp3-preview/9153bcc4d7bef50eb80a809fa34e694f2854e539?cid=null",
                "offsetInMilliseconds": 0
                  }
                }
              }
            ],
            "shouldEndSession" : true
        }
    }';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the above doc:
https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/alexa/alexa-skills-kit/docs/custom-audioplayer-interface-reference#playbacknearlyfinished-request

and then do this to enqueue the second song

In PHP, the way you are handling other requests, you can handle AudioRequest too. For example.

```
$data       = file_get_contents("php://input");
$jsonData   = json_decode($data);

if($jsonData->request->type === "AudioPlayer.PlaybackNearlyFinished")
{ 
    $response = '{
        "version" : "1.0",
        "response" : {
            "directives": [
              {
                "type": "AudioPlayer.Play",
                "playBehavior": "ENQUEUE",
                "audioItem": {
                  "stream": {
                "token": "track2",
                "expectedPreviousToken": "track1",
                "url": "Your URL",
                "offsetInMilliseconds": 3
                  }
                }
              }
            ],
            "shouldEndSession" : true
        }
    }';
    echo $response;
}
```

This is the way you can handle all the AudioRequest.

Answer (score 2):

You need to wait for the AudioPlayer.PlaybackNearlyFinished request from Alexa. At that point, you can enqueue the next track to be played. It will come near the conclusion of the playback of the currently playing track.

Information on it is here:
https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/alexa/alexa-skills-kit/docs/custom-audioplayer-interface-reference#playbacknearlyfinished-request

When replying with a directive to PlaybackNearlyFinished, be sure that:

- You set the playBehavior to ENQUEUE
  This will cause the next track to start after the current one finishes
- You do NOT include the outputSpeech field
  outputSpeech is not allowed when out of session. The session ends when the first stream begins playback.

This blog post that I wrote goes into more detail on approaches to developing and testing for the AudioPlayer interface:
https://bespoken.tools/blog/2016/10/10/unit-testing-alexa-skills

Comment: How to know that AudioPlayer.PlaybackNearlyFinished has been fired in php?

Comment: I am able to play the first song but don't know how and what to do to go for the second,third and so on..

Comment: And I am using PHP language so not sure whether it is possible in php or not.